# How can I stack my hyperlink images on top of each other in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, alignment

It's my first time creating a website and I want to add these images as hyperlinks stacked on top of each other. However, they're stacked horizontally even though I was following a tutorial.

This is my HTML code:

```css
.socials {
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    padding-right: 16px;
    
}

.social {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="socials">
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com" class="social">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ffffff" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M4.98 3.5c0 1.381-1.11 2.5-2.48 2.5s-2.48-1.119-2.48-2.5c0-1.38 1.11-2.5 2.48-2.5s2.48 1.12 2.48 2.5zm.02 4.5h-5v16h5v-16zm7.982 0h-4.968v16h4.969v-8.399c0-4.67 6.029-5.052 6.029 0v8.399h4.988v-10.131c0-7.88-8.922-7.593-11.018-3.714v-2.155z"/></svg>                    </a>
    </a>    
    <a href="http://www.github.com" class="social">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ffffff" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z"/></svg>
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.instagram.com" class="social">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ffffff" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2.163c3.204 0 3.584.012 4.85.07 3.252.148 4.771 1.691 4.919 4.919.058 1.265.069 1.645.069 4.849 0 3.205-.012 3.584-.069 4.849-.149 3.225-1.664 4.771-4.919 4.919-1.266.058-1.644.07-4.85.07-3.204 0-3.584-.012-4.849-.07-3.26-.149-4.771-1.699-4.919-4.92-.058-1.265-.07-1.644-.07-4.849 0-3.204.013-3.583.07-4.849.149-3.227 1.664-4.771 4.919-4.919 1.266-.057 1.645-.069 4.849-.069zm0-2.163c-3.259 0-3.667.014-4.947.072-4.358.2-6.78 2.618-6.98 6.98-.059 1.281-.073 1.689-.073 4.948 0 3.259.014 3.668.072 4.948.2 4.358 2.618 6.78 6.98 6.98 1.281.058 1.689.072 4.948.072 3.259 0 3.668-.014 4.948-.072 4.354-.2 6.782-2.618 6.979-6.98.059-1.28.073-1.689.073-4.948 0-3.259-.014-3.667-.072-4.947-.196-4.354-2.617-6.78-6.979-6.98-1.281-.059-1.69-.073-4.949-.073zm0 5.838c-3.403 0-6.162 2.759-6.162 6.162s2.759 6.163 6.162 6.163 6.162-2.759 6.162-6.163c0-3.403-2.759-6.162-6.162-6.162zm0 10.162c-2.209 0-4-1.79-4-4 0-2.209 1.791-4 4-4s4 1.791 4 4c0 2.21-1.791 4-4 4zm6.406-11.845c-.796 0-1.441.645-1.441 1.44s.645 1.44 1.441 1.44c.795 0 1.439-.645 1.439-1.44s-.644-1.44-1.439-1.44z"/></svg>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate, I replaced your SVG's with Images. You can use `flex-box` with `flex-direction: column;` to have your images stack. Also, for good measures, I positioned it in the center. See below.

```css
.socials {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="socials">
   <a href="http://www.linkedin.com" class="social">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/000/fff">              
   </a>    
   <a href="http://www.github.com" class="social">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/000/fff">         
   </a>
   <a href="http://www.instagram.com" class="social">
   <img src="https://dummyimage.com/50/000/fff">           
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## with CSS GRID

css grid automatically puts everything in row mode :)

...few lines and your work is complete!

-or with flex-box it automatically transforms everything into columns, so you need to write an extra CSS property `flex-direction`

so go for `display: grid;` I think is the best, simplest solution :)

```css
.socials {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.social svg {
    fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="socials">
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com" class="social">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ffffff" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M4.98 3.5c0 1.381-1.11 2.5-2.48 2.5s-2.48-1.119-2.48-2.5c0-1.38 1.11-2.5 2.48-2.5s2.48 1.12 2.48 2.5zm.02 4.5h-5v16h5v-16zm7.982 0h-4.968v16h4.969v-8.399c0-4.67 6.029-5.052 6.029 0v8.399h4.988v-10.131c0-7.88-8.922-7.593-11.018-3.714v-2.155z"/></svg>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.github.com" class="social">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ffffff" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 0c-6.626 0-12 5.373-12 12 0 5.302 3.438 9.8 8.207 11.387.599.111.793-.261.793-.577v-2.234c-3.338.726-4.033-1.416-4.033-1.416-.546-1.387-1.333-1.756-1.333-1.756-1.089-.745.083-.729.083-.729 1.205.084 1.839 1.237 1.839 1.237 1.07 1.834 2.807 1.304 3.492.997.107-.775.418-1.305.762-1.604-2.665-.305-5.467-1.334-5.467-5.931 0-1.311.469-2.381 1.236-3.221-.124-.303-.535-1.524.117-3.176 0 0 1.008-.322 3.301 1.23.957-.266 1.983-.399 3.003-.404 1.02.005 2.047.138 3.006.404 2.291-1.552 3.297-1.23 3.297-1.23.653 1.653.242 2.874.118 3.176.77.84 1.235 1.911 1.235 3.221 0 4.609-2.807 5.624-5.479 5.921.43.372.823 1.102.823 2.222v3.293c0 .319.192.694.801.576 4.765-1.589 8.199-6.086 8.199-11.386 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12z"/></svg>
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com" class="social">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#ffffff" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2.163c3.204 0 3.584.012 4.85.07 3.252.148 4.771 1.691 4.919 4.919.058 1.265.069 1.645.069 4.849 0 3.205-.012 3.584-.069 4.849-.149 3.225-1.664 4.771-4.919 4.919-1.266.058-1.644.07-4.85.07-3.204 0-3.584-.012-4.849-.07-3.26-.149-4.771-1.699-4.919-4.92-.058-1.265-.07-1.644-.07-4.849 0-3.204.013-3.583.07-4.849.149-3.227 1.664-4.771 4.919-4.919 1.266-.057 1.645-.069 4.849-.069zm0-2.163c-3.259 0-3.667.014-4.947.072-4.358.2-6.78 2.618-6.98 6.98-.059 1.281-.073 1.689-.073 4.948 0 3.259.014 3.668.072 4.948.2 4.358 2.618 6.78 6.98 6.98 1.281.058 1.689.072 4.948.072 3.259 0 3.668-.014 4.948-.072 4.354-.2 6.782-2.618 6.979-6.98.059-1.28.073-1.689.073-4.948 0-3.259-.014-3.667-.072-4.947-.196-4.354-2.617-6.78-6.979-6.98-1.281-.059-1.69-.073-4.949-.073zm0 5.838c-3.403 0-6.162 2.759-6.162 6.162s2.759 6.163 6.162 6.163 6.162-2.759 6.162-6.163c0-3.403-2.759-6.162-6.162-6.162zm0 10.162c-2.209 0-4-1.79-4-4 0-2.209 1.791-4 4-4s4 1.791 4 4c0 2.21-1.791 4-4 4zm6.406-11.845c-.796 0-1.441.645-1.441 1.44s.645 1.44 1.441 1.44c.795 0 1.439-.645 1.439-1.44s-.644-1.44-1.439-1.44z"/></svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> if you want to learn more about grid: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/css-grid/create-your-first-css-grid
> this really help me a lot to understand it